# shell script adjusment - not working fine with cron

Tags: bash, shell, cron

i used this bash script to check services running or not if running  the script will exit if else it will run another script which gona execute some commands 
and once done it will be exit 
my issue is when i run my script manuly its works fine but when i run it with cron its not running and not executed correctly here is my script

```
  #!/bin/sh
  SERVICE='loop2.sh'

  if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
 then
     echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
 else
 /home//www/loop2.sh
 fi
```

any adjust to my script to be working fine in cron

Answer (score 1):

You're not being very specific. What error are you seeing ?

Note that processes run under cron with a cut-down environment. In particular environment variables such as PATH will be much reduced from your interactive shell.

1. log your scripts stdout/stderr e.g. `myscript 2>&1 >/tmp/script.log`
2. check your environment is as expected via the `env` command in your script
3. does this script *really* do what you want ? And interact with cron how you wish ? If your service isn't running you spawn a new one, but I'd expect you to put it in the background, thus making it a daemon and not a (grand)child of the `cron` process
4. is your script executable by whichever user it's executed by under `cron` ?

Comment: there is no error lets say i run sh myshell.sh its run okey and no errors and execute til exit but if i add it to cron like run every 5 mints */5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/www/myshell.sh its just not running